# How can I efficiently extend one dimension of a multidimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays:

data.shape -> (100, 81, 121, 6, 3)
(n_samples, latitude, longitude, features, level)

labels.shape -> (100, 2)
(n_samples, target_value)

All I want is to append the two vectors of labels to the 4 dimension of data. So my goal is to end up with a new array like this:
result.shape -> (100, 81, 121, 8, 3).

I'm looking for an efficient solution with numpy, xarray, pandas, etc. But find none. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what doesn't work? please post MCVE

Comment: You could make `result` with the desired shape (and dtype), and do sliced copy of the two arrays.  Speed should be similar to the concatenate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) to broadcast the smaller array to bigger array's shape and then concatenate with it along the axis of concatenation -

```
In [215]: data = np.random.rand(100,81,121,6,3)

In [216]: labels = np.random.rand(100,2)

In [218]: labels_ext = np.broadcast_to(labels[:,None,None,:,None],(100,81,121,2,3))

In [219]: np.concatenate((data,labels_ext),axis=3).shape
Out[219]: (100, 81, 121, 8, 3)
```

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for! Thank you Divakar. It does exactly what I wanted it to do.